# Get data from multiple tables in one result set in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

In a small library/research database application I am working on, I have a page where a user can view all of the resources they have submitted.

I have three tables for different resources - Books, Journals and Conferences. The tables look like this:

```
mysql> desc book;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| author        | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| publishedyear | char(4)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title         | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| edition       | int(3) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| publisher     | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| place         | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| image         | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| isbn          | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| callnumber    | varchar(30)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status        | int(1) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| abstract      | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| toc           | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| problems      | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| futurework    | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| registered    | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mid           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| iid           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

```
mysql> desc journal;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| author        | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| publishedyear | char(4)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title         | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| journaltitle  | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| volume        | int(3) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| issue         | int(5) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pagenumbers   | varchar(15)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| image         | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| isbn          | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| callnumber    | varchar(30)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status        | int(1) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| abstract      | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| toc           | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| problems      | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| futurework    | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| registered    | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mid           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| iid           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
19 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

```
mysql> desc conference;
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| author         | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| publishedyear  | char(4)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title          | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| conferencename | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| location       | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| conferencedate | varchar(15)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pagenumbers    | varchar(15)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| image          | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| isbn           | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| callnumber     | varchar(30)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status         | int(1) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| abstract       | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| toc            | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| problems       | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| futurework     | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| registered     | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mid            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| iid            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
19 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I am trying to do is very simple, but I can't seem to find a simple SQL command for it. Searching on stack overflow and google for "selecting data from multiple tables" and other similar searches returned a lot of results for ridiculously complex joins, unions, etc for databases and operations that are much more complicated than what I am trying to do here.

Is there not something like:

```
Select * FROM book, journal, conference WHERE mid = 4'
```

This returns an error: "field mid is ambiguous".

Thanks!

**EDIT - As martijn pointed out, a lot of my problem is coming from the design of my database.

Two solutions seem to be to either redesign the database and combine `book`, `journal` and `conference` into one table `resources`

or, as a very hackish workaround

To do three separate queries:

```
SELECT * FROM book where mid = 4

SELECT * FROM journal WHERE mid = 4

SELECT * FROM conference WHERE mid =4
```

and then combine those result sets using PHP.

Comment: you have to use join or cross join by making primary and foriegn key relations. And the error is because the mid is exists in all of your selected table how does query knows on the basis of which **mid** retrieve the record

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, the reason you're having trouble because of the database design. The definitions of the three tables are (as far as I can see) identical. Maybe you should make it one table with an `ENUM` field specifying if the entry is a book, journal or conference.
EDIT: I've just seen this is not an easy option: you'll still need separate tables for the info that is specific to books, journals and conferences.

If you do not want to do this, you need to specify you question a little more. Do you want to have the rows from the three tables which have `mid` equal to 4? In this case, you have to use `UNION`. If you want one line giving you the book, journal, and conference with `mid = 4`, use a `JOIN`, as thomasrutter pointed out already.

EDIT: now that you point out exactly what you want the query to return, it is probably best to use 'mu is too short''s solution. Adding the field is an elegant solution (+1 for that).

Still, I think you should consider using the `ENUM` option. I do not know what functionality would break, but fixing queries would boil down to adding a `WHERE kind = 'journal'` if you're selecting from `jounals` originally.

Comment: mid is "member id". Believe me, I would love to redesign the database but it would break a lot of other functionality. Ultimately what I am trying to accomplish would be the same as if you did "SELECT * FROM book WHERE mid=4" "SELECT * FROM journal WHERE mid = 4" "SELECT * FROM conference WHERE mid = 4" and combined all of those result sets into one, if that makes any sense. I have a method that will go through this massive result set and generate an array objects that have properties based on columns and their values.

BTW - how to wrap code in comments? tried 'code' and [code]...

Comment: mu is too short's solution didn't work as the tables have a different number of columns.  

Selecting this as the answer as it is a database (and application) design issue. Going to bite the bullet and try to combine these all into one table. Thanks.

Comment: @sanukcm: I've reviewed your tables again. The main difference is in the extra info fields, which will probably make it hard to combine the tables (which I've should have seen earlier). You're probably better off doing three queries.

Comment: @sanukcm: you can sort out the schema issues with aliases and laterals to pad things out but that would be a bit of a hack. That said, revisiting your schema sounds like a good plan; maybe smaller pieces would work but it is hard to say without knowing how the data is accessed and such. As usual, it is mostly a question of which type if pain you want and when you want it :)

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for a UNION:

```
select 'book' as item_type, * from book where mid = 4
union all
select 'journal' as item_type, * from journal where mid = 4
union all
select 'conference' as item_type, * from conference where mid = 4
```

Assuming of course that you're trying to search all three tables at once and they really do have the same column structure. In a real application you would, of course, explicitly list the columns rather than using `*` to ensure that the columns came out in the right order. Also, I've taken the liberty of adding an `item_type` so that you can figure out where table each entry came from.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with a *join*.

The simplest type of join in MySQL is very similar to what you tried already.  The problem with what you had is that it didn't know which "mid" you were referring to.  In reality you want to join on all three of them being equal to a constant.

```
SELECT * FROM book, journal, conference
WHERE book.mid = 4 AND journal.mid = 4 AND conference.mid = 4
```

Which should be pretty easy to understand.

There are other ways to express the same join - for example:

```
SELECT * FROM
  book
  INNER JOIN journal ON journal.mid = book.mid
  INNER JOIN conference ON conference.mid = book.mid
WHERE
  book.mid = 4
```

... which expresses exactly the same thing, but once you get more complex queries than this, separating the join conditions from other WHERE clauses may make for better reading - once you're familiar with the syntax.

It should be noted that joins are for when you want to *combine* rows from the tables.  If there are multiple conferences, or multiple books, etc, all with the desired "mid" value, then a row will be returned for every *combination* of these.  So if there's 4 books, 2 conferences and 2 journals with the same "mid" value, you'll get 4 x 2 x 2 = 16 rows returned.  This is because in this instance you're telling MySQL "tell me every combination of book, conference and journal you can find with these values".

I don't know what the application is, so I don't know if this is what you want.  If you don't want this, however, and you're just interested in retrieving the rows from each table separately and not combining them, then it's probably better expressed as three separate queries.

Comment: This only works if `mid` is a field which connects books to journals and conferences. It is not obvious to me that it does. @sanukcm: what do mid and iid mean?

Comment: Thomas, thanks for your very descriptive answer. Unfortunately, this only works if a user has submitted resources of all three types.

If you have a user who, for example has only submitted Journals, this query returned an empty set.

Comment: @Martijn I've added a note to the bottom now describing this a bit.  I, too, don't know if sanukcm wanted to *combine* rows based on `mid`.  So I've added that description.  Cheers.

Comment: @sanukcm it sounds like you don't want a join then, and you want to query the tables separately.  That way, you'll get a list of all the books with that "mid" value, all the journals with that value, and all the conferences with that value.

Comment: @thomas, that's exactly what I want. I think I will just do three separate queries and combine them in a php data structure. Thanks!